# Комбинированная анимация вызывает ошибки на высоких скоростях

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

У меня есть код

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class Rad(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super(Rad, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(50, 50)
        self.radio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.setText(text)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.radio)
        lay.addWidget(self.label)

        self.animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation()
        self.animation.setDuration(2)
        self.animation.valueChanged.connect(self.on_value_changed)
        self.animation.setStartValue(100)
        self.animation.setEndValue(0)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QVariant")
    def on_value_changed(self, val):
        pos = self.pos()
        pos.setY(val)
        self.move(pos)

    def swap_values(self):
        self.animation.blockSignals(True)
        start_value = self.animation.startValue()
        end_value = self.animation.endValue()
        self.animation.setStartValue(end_value)
        self.animation.setEndValue(start_value)
        self.animation.blockSignals(False)


class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.buts = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self, exclusive=True)
        wid_1 = Rad("but-200", self)
        wid_1.setStyleSheet("background:brown;")
        wid_1.move(200, 0)

        wid_2 = Rad("but-100", self)
        wid_2.setStyleSheet("background:yellow;")
        wid_2.move(100, 0)

        wid_3 = Rad("but-0", self)
        wid_3.setStyleSheet("background:green;")
        wid_3.move(0, 0)

        self.buts.addButton(wid_1.radio, 0)
        self.buts.addButton(wid_2.radio, 1)
        self.buts.addButton(wid_3.radio, 2)

        self.buts.buttonToggled.connect(self.on_button_toggled)

        self.group = QtCore.QSequentialAnimationGroup(self)

        self.last_widget = None

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtWidgets.QAbstractButton, bool)
    def on_button_toggled(self, button, state):
        if state:
            wid = button.parent()
            if self.group.animationCount() > 0:
                self.group.takeAnimation(0)
            if isinstance(self.last_widget, Rad):
                self.last_widget.swap_values()
                self.group.addAnimation(self.last_widget.animation)
            wid.swap_values()
            self.group.addAnimation(wid.animation)
            self.group.start()
            self.last_widget = wid


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.resize(500, 500)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

И когда я устанавливаю `.setDuration()` меньше 50 то вижу вот такую ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я знаю что могу просто не ставить `.setDuration()` меньше 50
Но это не значит что ошибка не может появится на значении больше 50

еще я заметил что изо того что `.setStartValue()` и `.setEndValue()` инвертированы
мне постоянно приходится устанавливать `.move()` каждый раз когда мне надо поменять
`.setStartValue()`

Я бы хотел знать как это исправить

Update

Хоть и весьма топорно но я смог вывернуть анимацию обратно

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class Rad(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super(Rad, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(50, 50)
        self.radio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.setText(text)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.radio)
        lay.addWidget(self.label)

        self.animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation()
        self.animation.setDuration(1000)
        self.animation.valueChanged.connect(self.on_value_changed)
        self.animation.setStartValue(0)
        self.animation.setEndValue(100)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QVariant")
    def on_value_changed(self, val):
        pos = self.pos()
        pos.setY(val)
        self.move(pos)

    def swap_values(self):
        self.animation.blockSignals(True)
        start_value = self.animation.startValue()
        end_value = self.animation.endValue()
        self.animation.setStartValue(end_value)
        self.animation.setEndValue(start_value)
        self.animation.blockSignals(False)


class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.buts = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self, exclusive=True)
        wid_1 = Rad("but-200", self)
        wid_1.setStyleSheet("background:brown;")
        wid_1.setObjectName(u"wid_1")
        wid_1.move(200, 0)

        wid_2 = Rad("but-100", self)
        wid_2.setStyleSheet("background:yellow;")
        wid_2.setObjectName(u"wid_2")
        wid_2.move(100, 0)

        wid_3 = Rad("but-0", self)
        wid_3.setStyleSheet("background:green;")
        wid_3.setObjectName(u"wid_3")
        wid_3.move(0, 0)

        self.buts.addButton(wid_1.radio, 0)
        self.buts.addButton(wid_2.radio, 1)
        self.buts.addButton(wid_3.radio, 2)

        self.buts.buttonToggled.connect(self.on_button_toggled)

        self.group = QtCore.QSequentialAnimationGroup(self)

        self.last_widget = None
        self.group_face = {}
        self.first = 1

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtWidgets.QAbstractButton, bool)
    def on_button_toggled(self, button, state):
        if state:
            self.wid = button.parent()
            self.group_face[self.wid.objectName()] = 0
            print("{}>{}".format(len(self.group_face),self.first))
            if len(self.group_face) > self.first:
                print("True")
                self.last_widget.swap_values()
                self.first = len(self.group_face)
            elif self.group.animationCount() > 0:
                print("False")
                self.wid.swap_values()
                self.last_widget.swap_values()
            if self.group.animationCount() > 0:
                self.group.takeAnimation(0)
            if isinstance(self.last_widget, Rad):
                self.group.addAnimation(self.last_widget.animation)
            self.group.addAnimation(self.wid.animation)
            self.group.start()
            self.last_widget = self.wid


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.resize(500, 500)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Я смог создать метод(функцию) которая хорошо работает на больших скоростях

```
    self.ask = False
    self.star = 0
    self.end = 100


def swap_values_2(self):
    print(self.ask)
    if self.ask :
        self.animation.setStartValue(self.star)
        self.animation.setEndValue(self.end)
    else:
        self.animation.setStartValue(self.end)
        self.animation.setEndValue(self.star)
    self.ask = not self.ask
```

но на медленных случается такой баг

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class Rad(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super(Rad, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(50, 50)
        self.radio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.setText(text)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.radio)
        lay.addWidget(self.label)

        self.animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation()
        self.animation.setDuration(2)                                      # !!! 2
#        self.animation.valueChanged.connect(self.on_value_changed)        # ---
        self.animation.setStartValue(100)
        self.animation.setEndValue(0)

#    @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QVariant")
    def on_value_changed(self, val):
        pos = self.pos()
        pos.setY(val)
        self.move(pos)

#    def swap_values(self):
#        self.animation.blockSignals(True)
#        start_value = self.animation.startValue()
#        end_value = self.animation.endValue()
#        self.animation.setStartValue(end_value)
#        self.animation.setEndValue(start_value)
#        self.animation.blockSignals(False)


class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.buts = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self, exclusive=True)
        wid_1 = Rad("but-200", self)
        wid_1.setStyleSheet("background:brown;")
        wid_1.move(200, 0)

        wid_2 = Rad("but-100", self)
        wid_2.setStyleSheet("background:yellow;")
        wid_2.move(100, 0)

        wid_3 = Rad("but-0", self)
        wid_3.setStyleSheet("background:green;")
        wid_3.move(0, 0)

        self.buts.addButton(wid_1.radio, 0)
        self.buts.addButton(wid_2.radio, 1)
        self.buts.addButton(wid_3.radio, 2)

        self.buts.buttonToggled.connect(self.on_button_toggled)

        self.group = QtCore.QSequentialAnimationGroup(self)
        self.group.currentAnimationChanged.connect(self.group_current_animation)      # +++ !!!
        self.last_widget = None

# +++   vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 
        self.fl_pos = True

    def group_current_animation(self):
        if self.fl_pos:
            self.group.currentAnimation().setStartValue(100)
            self.group.currentAnimation().setEndValue(0)
            self.wid.on_value_changed(100) 
        else:
            self.group.currentAnimation().setStartValue(0)
            self.group.currentAnimation().setEndValue(100)        
            self.wid.on_value_changed(0) 
            self.last_widget.on_value_changed(0) 

        self.fl_pos = not self.fl_pos
# +++   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtWidgets.QAbstractButton, bool)
    def on_button_toggled(self, button, state):
        if state:
            self.wid = button.parent()
            if self.group.animationCount() > 0:
                self.group.takeAnimation(0)
            if isinstance(self.last_widget, Rad):
#                self.last_widget.swap_values()
                self.group.addAnimation(self.last_widget.animation)

#            wid.swap_values()
            self.group.addAnimation(self.wid.animation)
            self.group.start()
            self.last_widget = self.wid


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.resize(300, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Но теперь не работает плавная анимация. `.setDuration(1000)`. Можно ли решить эту проблему. и оставить возможность контролировать скорость анимации?